flutter_local_notifications icon in res/drawable is unreadable or not working
I'm confused when I use my own icon my_icon in res/drawable it works but yesterday I tried it and it didn't work but when I tried using @mipmap/ic_launcher it worked
what's actually happening, help me, I'm confused
this is my code
import 'package:myflutterApp/Pages/home_pages.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;


class Notification_Manager {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        new AndroidInitializationSettings('my_icon');

    // var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
    //     requestAlertPermission: true,
    //     requestBadgePermission: true,
    //     requestSoundPermission: true,
    //     onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
    //         (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      // iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
      _handleNotificationTap(notificationResponse);
    });
  }

  void _handleNotificationTap(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    final String? payload = notificationResponse.payload;
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('Notification payload: $payload');
    }
    // Navigate to HomePage using GetX
    Get.to(() => Home_Pages());
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'myApp',
        'My Flutter App',
        channelDescription: 'My Flutter App build with Love',
        fullScreenIntent: true,
        playSound: true,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("my_sound_1"),
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
      ),
      // iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
    );
  }

  Future showNotification(
      {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payLoad}) async {
    return flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
  }

  Future<void> cancelNotification() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }


I have made sure that myicon is in res/drawable and my_sound_1 is in res/raw
I hope that there is someone who understands and can solve this problem. Thank you so that there will be no more confusing errors like this again.
